# Issue with NPOT Atlas (C++/iOS) using glTexCoordPointer

Tags: opengl-es

My app uses an atlas and reaches parts of it to display items using `glTexCoordPointer`.
It works well with power-of-two textures, but I wanted to use `NPOT` to reduce the amount of memory used.

Actually, the picture itself is well loaded with the linear filter and clamp-to-edge wrapping (the content displayed comes from the pic, even with alpha), but the display is deformed.
The coordinates are not the correct ones, and the "shape" is more a trapezoid than a rectangle.

I guessed I had to play with `glEnable()`, passing `GL_TEXTURE_2D` in the case of a `POT` texture, and `GL_APPLE_texture_2D_limited_npot` in the other case, but I cannot find a way to do so.
Also, I do not have the `GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB`, I don't know if it is an issue...

Anyone had the same kind of problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Since OpenGL-2 (i.e. for about 10 years) there are no longer constraints on the size of a regular texture. You can use whatever image size you want, it will just work.

Comment: Well, it works in term of picture loading, I can see that the content displayed is from the NPOT texture. 
The problem is that the coords (% of the texture passed through glTexcoordPointer) do not display at all what they are supposed to...

Comment: @ChristopheLargilliere: How does the texture look like if you simply map into onto a single large quad? Make sure it's been loaded correctly. Especially alignment issues can bite you hard with NPo2 (with Po2 textures you often were forced into a memory layout you simply couldn't misalign).

Comment: Hm, I'm no OpenGL Master, I'm trying to display the full texture (halved actually) on screen, a bit struggling.
BTW what can cause an alignment issue ?
I think there is some next POT problem or something alike, cause instead of a POT 2048*1024 texture I have a 1305*1023. The Y pos are OK (1023 being not really far from 1024...) and it's mostly the X pos that are messed up.
Maybe a pixel int calculation with mixed values gone wrong.

Comment: There's definitely something with the size.
Given a texture point of coords (X, Y) and texture size of (W, H), there is an x offset of Y * (NextPO2(W) - W)...
I think somewhere openGL considers the texture as a POT. I'm playing with the offsets to counter them but I guess there is a simple thing to do that would require less efforts.

Comment: @ChristopheLargilliere: Try what happens if you put a `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` right before the call to *glTexImage*.

Comment: That's... Amazing!
Thank you very much, it works great.
You spare me hours of struggle (and some hair too)